# Network protocol for surviving client IP address/network changes, among other problems

Tags: network-programming, network-protocols

Persistent connection to a mobile device is difficult.  Signal conditions can change rapidly, and connectivity types can also change.  For instance, I may want to stream audio to my phone as I leave my apartment (WiFi), take a bus (WiMax/LTE), transfer to the subway (intermittent CDMA, sometimes roaming on another carrier), and walk to work (WiMax/LTE and back to WiFi).  On this 15-minute trip alone I use at least 4 different IP addresses/networks, and experience all sorts of connectivity issues along the way.  However, there is rarely a total loss of connectivity to the Internet, and the times that the signal condition makes connectivity problematic only happen for small periods of time.

I'm looking for a protocol that allows roaming from network to network and is very tolerant of harsh network conditions, while maintaining virtual end-to-end connectivity.  This protocol would enable connections between a (usually) mobile device and some sort of proxy server which would relay regular TCP/UDP connections on behalf of the mobile device, over this tolerant protocol.

This protocol would sit around layer 3, and maybe even enable creation of virtual network interfaces that are tunneled through it.  Perhaps there is a VPN or SOCKS proxy solution that already meets these needs.

**Does such a protocol already exist?**

If not, I'm probably going to come up with one, but would rather piggy-back off of existing efforts first.

Comment: I don't see why? TCP will try it's best to maintain a connection with you, and it's pretty much up to the programmer to handle total connection losses with timeouts. Putting that on a new layer would not be good- Some people don't necessarily WANT to re-connect.

Comment: @DanRedux, It is my understanding that TCP connections are bound to a port and IP network.  Is that not true?  Also, I'm not interested in what some people don't want, I'm interested in what I'm trying to develop.  As you have said, as of now, it is up to the programmer at the application level to handle this type of thing.  Rather than fixing the problem per application, I am thinking of fixing it at a lower level.  All that being said, I'm very open to suggestions.  TCP goes a long way to reliability, but I don't believe it fits the requirement of changing networks.

Comment: If you can generate keys, trade them upon connection, and when a node changes IP, it should send the new IP as well as the key to the other node, so the other node can accept it. However, in the brief moment when they trade keys, it could be intercepted. To allow IP hopping safely might be impossible.

Comment: @MikePennington, I'm not concerned with the user side of all this.  I'm only worried about information on any existing protocols (if they exist) or things I should be thinking about, if I decide to end up making one myself.  For instance, since Dan brought up a good point about re-establishing the underlying TCP or UDP connection when an end point joins a new network.  Reconnecting safely/securely would be a concern, and general advice on how to handle such a situation would be helpful.  But yes, if a protocol that does most of this already exists, it would be great to know about it.

Comment: @MikePennington, Of course, if there is a full solution (commercial or otherwise, with client/server applications) that already exists, I would be interesting in hearing about that too.  In the end, I will be embedding something into my own applications (in the case of a protocol or some sort of component that provides easy usage of a protocol) or suggesting usage of a solution that already exists.

Comment: How about a P2P solution? Using a peer identity?

Comment: @SergioGarcia, I am open to any suggestion.  Can you provide more details how you propose such a system would work?  I am not familiar with the inner workings of Tor and what not.

Comment: @eggyal, Nothing is wrong with your answer!  I am quite pleased with your answer, have upvoted it, and have little doubt that I will award the bounty to you.  I've been looking into HIP, and it seems right along the lines of what I'm looking for.  I am leaving the bounty open until its end to see if there are other answers out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many efforts within the internetworking community to address precisely these "network mobility" concerns.

In particular, [Mobile IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_IP) (and its IPv6 big sister, [Proxy Mobile IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_Mobile_IP)) is a broad term for efforts to make IP addresses themselves portable across networks, however I doubt these technologies have reached sufficient maturation/deployment for production use today.

To undertake such mobility without support from the network requires a means of the host announcing to you its new address in an authenticated manner; this is what the [Host Identity Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_Identity_Protocol) is designed for, but it is still at the "experimental" stage of the RFC process.  From the abstract of [RFC 5201](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5201):

> HIP allows consenting hosts to securely establish and maintain shared
> IP-layer state, allowing separation of the identifier and locator
> roles of IP addresses, thereby enabling continuity of communications
> across IP address changes.

There are several open-source implementations that are known to interoperate.  Without claiming that this is a complete list, nor vouching for any of them (they're just a few picked off a Google search for "Host Identity Protocol implementations"), there is:

- [OpenHIP](http://www.openhip.org/) for multiple operating systems;
- [HIPL](https://launchpad.net/hipl) for Linux;
- [cutehip](http://code.google.com/p/cutehip/) for Java;
- [HIP for inter.net](http://hip4inter.net/) for *BSD/Linux.